# Could not add a value to IQueryable (DbContext)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext, iqueryable

I'm trying out MVC4 and I'm stuck on trying to create a data. My code doesn't add anything to the List. Here's my code on the controller's HttpPost Create Method

```
Script script = _db.Scripts.Single(d => d.Id == viewModel.ScriptId);
ScriptRequest scriptRequest = new ScriptRequest();
scriptRequest.Username = viewModel.Name;
scriptRequest.RequestedScript = script;
scriptRequest.Parameters = viewModel.OtherParam;
scriptRequest.DateRequested = DateTime.Today;
_db.ScriptRequests.ToList<ScriptRequest>().Add(scriptRequest);
_db.Save();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

When I debug, nothing is added to _db.ScriptRequest. I also tried other methods such as Concat but I still can't add a row. This is in mydefinition of a class that extends the DbContext class.

```
public DbSet<ScriptRequest> ScriptRequests { get; set; }

IQueryable<Parameter> IDarylToolDatasource.Parameters
{
     get { return Parameters; }
}

void IDarylToolDatasource.Save()
{
     SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from this line:

`_db.ScriptRequests.ToList<ScriptRequest>().Add(scriptRequest);`

`.ToList()` method in this line creates a `List<ScriptRequest>` into the memory and in the following of chain, you add the object to that in-memory list, NOT to your dbcontext.

Remove `.ToList()` and the problem will go away

Comment: I see now that it is not my dbContext but I could not proceed doing a .Add without the .ToList because the IQueryable has no defined method for that. Does this mean that I should create a new method that will do the .Add inside the DbContext class?

Comment: @dasap - Are your overriding something, somewhere ...? There is no problem with your dbcontext code. Unless you overridden some default behaviors...